# Getting a Java Array <init>

Tags: java, arrays, class, init

I have a class that has a constructor of the same name, and I'm trying to set all Index Array to "Open" first.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       

       Calendar info = new Calendar();

}
class Calendar{
    private String name;
    Calendar[] test= new Calendar[24];
    Calendar(){
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
            test[i] = new Calendar();      
            test[i].name = "Open";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work. What's the issue?

Comment: Ohhh nested calls... Hmm.. create another constructor Calendar (String name) and use it in the for loop of Calendar()

Comment: When I run it it's saying I'm getting a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError and it's saying having a problem at test[i] = new Calendar();

Comment: Yes problem is with recursive calls for calendar constructor

Comment: Do you really need 24 children inside each Calendar object? I would use different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the recursive calls of Calendar() constructor. Try the below code which uses another constructor for initialising test[] array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
   Calendar info = new Calendar();
}

class Calendar {
  private String name;
  Calendar[] test= new Calendar[24];
  Calendar() {
    for(int i = 0; i < this.test.length; i++){
        this.test[i] = new Calendar("Open");
      }
  }
  Calendar(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }
}
```